# How to keep a container running even if it does not have any running program in it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker to create a container whose purpose is to just serve the project files to other containers.

But when I am executing `docker-compose up` command, this container is stopping, since it does not have any running program in it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it correct way/thinking, to have a container which is serving other container the required files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is stopping container COMMAND?

If you don't want docker container to stop then add some command which never ends, e.g. `sleep infinity`.